# Is there a way to show/render the dataset value directly over doughnut chart in Chart JS, rather than showing them in tooltip once hovered

Tags: chart.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4nor.png)

As shown in the image above, I need to show the dataset right over the doughnut chart surface, Not in the tooltip (which is a default behaviour).

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

I tried below configuration, but it seems this doesn't works while I am creating custom plugin.

```
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: data,
  options: {
    plugins: {
      doughnutlabel: {
        labels: [{
          render: function (args) {
            return args.label + ': ' + args.value;
          },
          fontColor: '#000',
          fontSize: 12,
          fontStyle: 'bold',
          position: 'outside',
          arc: true
        }]
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: You may use [chart-js-datalabels](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/getting-started.html#getting-started) plugin, see [the doughnut example](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/samples/charts/doughnut.html)

Comment: Thanks Kikon, This is helpful. But It's seems like this we need to register this plugin that's not happening correctly. Whatever steps are mentioned following those getting console error - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'extend').

Comment: You may consider adding the code that is creating problems. I'd recommend you ask a new question -- that perfectly fits the stackoverflow profile - asking about errors in code

Comment: Somehow I am able to resolve the error, There was a dependency incompatibility, But now the error is different - 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76496142/while-trying-to-register-chartjs-plugin-datalabels-library-in-case-of-doughnut