# While trying to register "chartjs-plugin-datalabels" library in case of doughnut chart, Getting console error

Tags: chart.js

The error says:

`Error: "doughnut" is not a registered controller.`

Tried changing the char type but it's giving error for all the chart types.

chartjs-plugin-datalabels - https://v2_2_0--chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/getting-started.html#registration

Versions I am using:

- chart.js 4.3.0
- chartjs-plugin-datalabels 2.2.0

I tried like below -

```
import ChartDataLabels from 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels';
Chart.register(<ChartComponentLike>ChartDataLabels);
```

```
this.chart = new Chart('canvas', <ChartConfiguration>{
      plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
      type: 'doughnut',
      data: {
        labels: ['Data1', 'Data2'],
        datasets: [
          {
            data: [55, 45],
            backgroundColor: ['rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)', 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1)'],
            fill: false,
          },
        ],
      },
      options: {
        plugins: {
          datalabels: {
            backgroundColor: function(context) {
              return context.dataset.backgroundColor;
            },
            borderColor: 'white',
            borderRadius: 25,
            borderWidth: 2,
            color: 'white',
            display: function(context) {
              var dataset = context.dataset;
              var count = dataset.data.length;
              var value = dataset.data[context.dataIndex];
              return value > count * 1.5;
            },
            font: {
              weight: 'bold'
            },
            padding: 6,
            formatter: Math.round
          }
        },
    
        // Core options
        aspectRatio: 4 / 3,
        cutoutPercentage: 32,
        layout: {
          padding: 32
        },
        elements: {
          line: {
            fill: true
          },
          point: {
            hoverRadius: 7,
            radius: 5
          }
        },
      }
    });
```

Slackblitz link - https://stackblitz.com/edit/chartjs-doughnut-chart?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,node_modules%2Fchartjs-plugin-datalabels%2Ftypes%2Findex.d.ts

Comment: Your stackblitz didn't have the plugin included. I forked it and added the `chartjs-plugin-datalabels` dependency and did just the minimal setup, as [per the docs](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/getting-started.html#integration). Here's [the fork](https://stackblitz.com/edit/chartjs-doughnut-chart-fp3ugt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts). You don't need to register the plugin if you declare it in the `plugins` sections of the configuration object.

Comment: Fantastic, This is cool. But I remember I had included the plugin. Anyway, TYSM for the help.

Comment: The error you get seems to indicate that `chart.js` didn't register the controllers. In some environments you might need to start `chart.js` with 
 `import {Chart, registerables} from "./chart.js";
Chart.register(...registerables);`

This is not related to the plugin, it's setup remains the same.